# Create a separate table or store the data in a string?

Tags: sql-server-2019, c#

I'm building a simple job board (using MS SQL/ASP.NET core/C#) and have a question about the database design. I don't know how to decide whether I should create a separate table or not in certain situations.

I have the following tables:

- Job
- Category
- Industry
- Region

In the Job table, i store the salary in the 'Salary' field, but I also need to store the 'SalaryPeriod', i.e. how frequently the salary is paid: per year, month, week, day or hour.

Is it better to 1) create a SalaryPeriod table which contains the 5 options (yearly, monthly, etc.), or is it better to 2) store the salary period as a string the Job table?

I'm leaning towards #1 because:

- It's easier to maintain the data, for example if I need to edit, or add to the salary types (I don't think I'll modify the options to be honest, but you just never know)
- I don't have performance issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a definitive list of what salary frequencies are acceptable to your system they should be their own table, which is SalaryPeriod. This table will have a unique constraint on the frequency so there is only ever one row in it with the value 'daily' and one with 'hourly' etc.

Job references this table as a foreign key. Something like

```
create table dbo.Job
(
  ...
  SalaryPeriodFrequency ...
  ...
 , CONSTRAINT FK_Job_SalaryPeriod FOREIGN KEY (SalaryPeriodFrequency)
        REFERENCES dbo.SalaryPeriod (Frequency)
);
```

This way you can be sure values for each job can only ever come from the definitive list. Typos are avoided and people can't just invent new values as they choose.

If there is a UI SalaryPeriod is used to populate drop-downs and similar widgets.

SQL Server benefits from [having small keys](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/more-considerations-for-the-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-continues/) on tables. So people often add integer surrogate key columns. These are then referenced as foreign keys rather than the natural key. In this case a tinyint would likely suffice.

```
create table dbo.SalaryPeriod
(
  SalaryPeriodId tinyint not null,
  Frequency varchar(12) not null,
  ... 
  CONSTRAINT PK_SalaryPeriod
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (SalaryPeriodId),
  CONSTRAINT UQ_Frequency
    UNIQUE(Frequency) 
  ...
);
```

Of course the column & foreign key definition in Job change to reference this id instead.

Answer (score -1):

I would add a table for it with an int value as PK so you don't have the string values duplicated lots of times.
That will save space.
Also searching in the related table will be faster as searching for int values is faster than searching string values.